# Tukey five number summary in Python

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, scipy

I have been unable to find this function in any of the standard packages, so I wrote the one below. Before throwing it toward the Cheeseshop, however, does anyone know of an already published version? Alternatively, please suggest any improvements. Thanks.

```
def fivenum(v):
    """Returns Tukey's five number summary (minimum, lower-hinge, median, upper-hinge, maximum) for the input vector, a list or array of numbers based on 1.5 times the interquartile distance"""
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile
    try:
        np.sum(v)
    except TypeError:
        print('Error: you must provide a list or array of only numbers')
    q1 = scoreatpercentile(v,25)
    q3 = scoreatpercentile(v,75)
    iqd = q3-q1
    md = np.median(v)
    whisker = 1.5*iqd
    return np.min(v), md-whisker, md, md+whisker, np.max(v),
```

Comment: For whatever it's worth, matplotlib's `boxplot` http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot effectively does this, though calling it just to calculate the parameters would be clunky, to say the least...

Comment: Matlab's box plot does NOT calculate a 5 number summary. Q1 and the lower hinge are frequently identical, but not always! Box plot calculates Q1 using a certain method (there are many too choose from), but it is not guaranteed to produce Tukey's lower hinge.

Comment: Cf. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51801/interpreting-weird-box-plot/51806?noredirect=1#comment101742_51806

Comment: What is the rationale about +-whisker? q1 and q3 should be the 2nd and 4th number. md-wisker can be smaller than np.min(v). Feels like broken

Answer (score 33):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) `Series` and `DataFrame` have a `describe` method, which is similar to `R`'s `summary`:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: import pandas as pd

In [5]: s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100))

In [6]: s.describe()
Out[6]: 
count    100.000000
mean       0.540376
std        0.296250
min        0.002514
25%        0.268722
50%        0.593436
75%        0.831067
max        0.991971
```

`NAN`'s are handled correctly.

Comment: N.B. This may give you a different result that you intend. Describe may be using a different interpolation method than what is required for the `lower` and `upper` quartiles. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 9):

I would get rid of these two things:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile
```

You should be importing at the module level. This means that users will be aware of missing dependencies as soon as they import your module, rather than when they call the function.

```
try:
    sum(v)
except TypeError:
    print('Error: you must provide a list or array of only numbers')
```

Several problems with this:

1. Don't type check in Python. Document what the function takes.
2. How do you know callers will see this? They might not be running at a console, and even if they are, they might not want your error message interfering with their output.
3. Don't type check in Python.

If you do want to raise some sort of exception for **invalid** data (**not** type checking), either let an existing exception propagate, or wrap it in your own exception type.

Comment: Good comments both. The imports are there just as a placeholder for when it will be a module. The exception handling I'll also take up. Thanks.

Comment: You already have a module (in python, all code is contained in a module).  Just do your imports at the top level, outside the function.  Not only is it arguably "more correct", but if/when you add another function to the file you won't have to write the import statements again.

Comment: It's not exactly right to refer to what's happening as type checking, just bad error reporting. The code leaves the client code free to call it with `v` equal to anything that can be passed to `sum`. That's completely correct.

Comment: I use quite often delayed imports inside a function. In a larger package not everyone uses every function, so we don't need to import everything by default. I think this depends a lot on the context.

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody ever needs a version that works with `NaN` in the data, here is my modification. I didn't want to change the original poster answer to avoid confusion.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile
from scipy.stats import nanmedian

def fivenum(v):
    """Returns Tukey's five number summary (minimum, lower-hinge, median, upper-hinge, maximum) for the input vector, a list or array of numbers based on 1.5 times the interquartile distance"""
    try:
        np.sum(v)
    except TypeError:
        print('Error: you must provide a list or array of only numbers')
    q1 = scoreatpercentile(v[~np.isnan(v)],25)
    q3 = scoreatpercentile(v[~np.isnan(v)],75)
    iqd = q3-q1
    md = nanmedian(v)
    whisker = 1.5*iqd
    return np.nanmin(v), md-whisker, md, md+whisker, np.nanmax(v),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Python, but the return is calculated incorrectly: it should be max(min(v), q1-whisker) for the lower bound and min (max(v), q3+whisker) for the upper bound.  It is how it's done in R (the `summary()` function), and that's what shows up on the boxplots in `matplotlib.pyplot` and in R.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
from statstools import run
from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile

data=np.random.randn(5)

return (min(data), md-whisker, md, md+whisker, max(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal, but it gets the job done.  :)

```
import numpy as np
[round(np.percentile(results[:,4], i), 1) for i in [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50]]
```

Comment: It does not handle NaNs, but for that there is np.nanpercentile

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
# np_array = np.array(np.random.random(100))
np.percentile(np_array, [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])
```

percentiles selection can be configured with the `interpolation` argument which is `linear` by default

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def fivenum(x):
    series=pd.Series(x)
    mi = series.min()
    q1 = series.quantile(q=0.25, interpolation='nearest')
    me = series.median()
    q3 = series.quantile(q=0.75, interpolation='nearest')
    ma = series.max()
    return pd.Series([mi, q1, me, q3, ma], index=['min', 'q1', 'median', 'q3', 'max'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).